# Can't get the id url from next js and use it with axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, axios

I've been trying to make a get request with axios, but it doesn't work because the id const doesn't load and is marked as undefined. Here is my code:

```
import Head from 'next/head'
import axios from 'axios'
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'


export default function QuejaID() {
    const router = useRouter()
    const id = router.query.id
    console.log(id)
    const [queja, setQueja] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {
        async function request() {
            await axios.get(
                `http://localhost:3000/quejas/${id}`
            ).then((response) => {
                setQueja(response.data)
                console.log(response)
            }).catch(err => { console.log(err) })
        }
        request()
    }, []);

    return (
        <>
            <Head>
                <title>Quejas</title>
                <meta name="description" content="queja" />
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
                <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
            </Head>
            <main>
                {queja ? <div className="container d-flex justify-content-center">
                    <div className="card text-center w-75 m-5">
                        <div className="card-header">{queja._id}</div>
                        <div className="card-body">
                            <h5 className="card-title">{queja.queja}</h5>
                        </div>
                        <div className="card-footer text-muted">{queja.createdAt}</div>
                    </div>
                </div> : <div>No hay ninguna queja con ese ID</div>}
            </main>
        </>
    )
}
```

So I tried with that and I get an error with axios because it's undefined.

Comment: Access the router query ID inside of your useEffect and don’t assign it in the component body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `id` to the dependency array

```
useEffect(() => {
        async function request() {
            await axios.get(
                `http://localhost:3000/quejas/${id}`
            ).then((response) => {
                setQueja(response.data)
                console.log(response)
            }).catch(err => { console.log(err) })
        }
        request()
    }, [id]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the hook `useRouter`. Since you are not using Server-Side Rendering, the object `router.query` will be an empty Object hence why `router.query.id` is undefined.
I suggest you pass the id using serversideprops :

```
export default function QuejaID({id}) {
    const [queja, setQueja] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {
        async function request() {
            await axios.get(
                `http://localhost:3000/quejas/${id}`
            ).then((response) => {
                setQueja(response.data)
                console.log(response)
            }).catch(err => { console.log(err) })
        }
        request()
    }, []);

    return (
        <>
            //Your Code
        </>
    )
}

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const router = useRouter()
  const id = router.query.id

  return {
    props: {id},
  }
}
```